# SELECT 2 rows of the same column value

Tags: mysql

I have data that looks like

```
id   val
--------
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    3
8    3
9    3
```

I'd like to fetch the id (and value) of two randomly chosen rows for each value, something like:

```
id   val
--------
2    1
3    1
4    2
6    2
8    3
9    3
```

**[EDIT]**

I use MySQL v5.7

**[SOLUTION]**

I finally found another solution to my problem which is more compact and more useful if for example I want to limit the results to 25 `id` per value

```
SELECT val, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY RAND() SEPARATOR ','), ',', 2)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY val
```

The idea is to group by `val`, concatenate the corresponding `id` in a string and taking a substring of the desired length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT t.val,
       @id := (SELECT t2.id FROM tbl_values t2 WHERE t2.val=t.val ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) id1,
       (SELECT t2.id FROM tbl_values t2 WHERE t2.val=t.val and t2.id<>@id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) id2
FROM  tbl_values t
GROUP by 1
```

[db fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wvkhVmTqcMMFDMWHENkp9c/2)

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL 8.0 you could use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT id, val
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY val ORDER BY RAND()) AS rn
      FROM tab) sub
WHERE rn <=2;
```

**[DB-Fiddle.com Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5jrhJUr789WwwMLEiwdweM/0)**

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
SELECT val, MIN(id)
FROM data
GROUP BY val
```

Comment: it just returns the minimum id for each value

Comment: You really need a "RANDOM" id, rather than an "ARBITRARY" one?